# Extract only number from text with Regex and Notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I would like know how to extract numbers from text with regex and Notepad++;

Text with numbers (example):

> 403567 ES  VISA    CREDIT  CLASSIC BANCO BILBAO VIZCAYA ARGENTARIA S.A. (BBVA)
> 403568 ES  VISA    DEBIT   CLASSIC BANCO BILBAO VIZCAYA ARGENTARIA S.A. (BBVA)
> 403569 ES  VISA    DEBIT   ELECTRON    BANCO BILBAO VIZCAYA ARGENTARIA S.A. (BBVA)
> 403642 ES  VISA    CREDIT  PLATINUM    BANCO BILBAO VIZCAYA ARGENTARIA S.A. (BBVA)
> 404134 ES  VISA    DEBIT   CLASSIC BANCO BILBAO VIZCAYA ARGENTARIA S.A. (BBVA)

Desire result:

> 403567
>
> 403568
>
> 403569
>
> 403642
>
> 404134

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is no negation or lookaround needed here. Have you made *any effort at all* to do this yourself? It's also very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eGzPNz/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
search: (\d+).*
replace: \1
```